# SP Designer 2013: Can I reduce redundancy between action steps and transition conditions?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I used to have a 2010 Workflow that had conditions like this:
[image]

I feel like the best way to write this in SP Designer 2013 is like this, but is there a better way:
[image]

Comment: You could set a workflow variable in the first `If-Else` statement called something like `varChangeAwaiting` and set it to a specific value. Then you can just do the second `If-Else` statement as `if varChangeAwaiting equals <value>`. Then if the boolean equation changes, you just have to change it in one spot (the first `If-Else` and not the second. Let me know if that helps or need a better explanation.

Comment: KGlasier:  Thanks for your comment!  Let me make sure I'm understanding completely:  EDIT (line breaks don't work).....    So in the workflow action steps, I make a workflow variable, and set it to true, then when I get to the transition section, I just reference that variable and make the logic choices there, instead of the long conditional - correct?

Comment: Yes I think that's what you want to do. I'll make a post about it just to make sure it's clear. Sorry I commented before your EDIT. Deleted my last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a local variable in SPD Workflow called `varChangeAwaiting` and set it to a `boolean` type, as follows:

[image]

Then set your `If-Else` up as you already have it but add the local variable. Sorry for not having the **exact** same `if-else` statement as you, but I did this in a bit of a rush.

[image]

Does that make sense? Now if you ever have to change the `if-else` you can just change it in one spot and the boolean will still flip. There's a chance you'll need to do a `Set Variable: varChangeAwaiting to No` at the top of your stage to initialize the variable, but it might default to `No`.

Comment: This makes good sense.  Bummer SP's not just in python, but this is a big improvement.  Thanks!

Comment: @phfb I wish we could use some sort of programming language, at least. Would make life so much easier on our end.